# private WCF service constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I know for a fact that the static constructor of a WCF service will be shared for all users, how about the private constructor? is it per user?

```
public partial class MyWCF : IMyWCF
{
    static MyWC()
    {
        // caching stuff here, used by all users
    }

    private MyWC()
    {
       // is it per user?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you only have a single instance of MyWCF. You probably don't, so the answer is probably not.

If you would have a single instance you would had this attribute on top of your service:

```
[ServiceBehaviour(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public partial class MyWCF : IMyWCF
{
}
```

In fact, it doesn't matter at all if it's private or not. That only control who can instantiate it.

Comment: Don't have it, so I can safely assume I am ok?

Comment: @MIH I don't know what ok means for you. But if you haven't specified otherwise you create an instance per session.

Comment: Is it really required to instantiate your Service using private/static constructors?

Comment: I don't think so. WCF does that for you.